# solr phrase frequency count

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Hi all is there any way to find frequency of a phrase in a document in solr.
i have a document like below
i need to find how many times the phrase is repeating in the document.

sample input:

1) "Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages"

2) "35 U.S.C. § 271(e)(2)(A)"

output : count of the phrase in the document

`
{
    "id":1,
    "filecontent": "Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages, typically consisting of alphabetic and numeric characters, between two or more users of mobile phones, tablets, desktops/laptops, or other devices. Text messages may be sent over a cellular network, or may also be sent via an Internet connection.

The term originally referred to messages sent using the Short Message Service (SMS). It has grown beyond alphanumeric text to include multimedia messages (known as MMS) containing digital images, videos, and sound content, as well as ideograms known as emoji (happy faces, sad faces, and other icons).

As of 2017, text messages ABC are used by youth and adults for personal, family and social purposes and in business. Governmental and non-governmental organizations use text messaging for communication between colleagues. As with emailing, in the 2010s, the sending of short informal messages has become an accepted part of many cultures.[1] This makes texting a quick and easy way to communicate with friends and colleagues, including in contexts where a call would be impolite or inappropriate (e.g., calling very late at night or when one knows the other person is busy with family or work activities). Like e-mail and voice mail, and unlike calls (in which the caller hopes to speak directly with the recipient), texting does not require the caller and recipient to both be free at the same moment; this permits communication even between busy individuals. Text messages can also be used to interact with automated systems, for example, to order products or services from e-commerce websites, or to participate 35 U.S.C. § 271(e)(2)(A) in online contests. Advertisers and service providers use direct text marketing to send messages to mobile users about promotions, payment due dates, and other notifications instead of using postal mail, email, or voicemail. by youth and adults for personal, by youth and adults for personal, by youth and adults for personal, messaging , textx"
}`

Comment: How long can the query phrases be? i.e. can you limit the number of tokens merged to a phrase to 12? 16? etc. - that would allow you to generate shingles for each sequence of tokens.

Comment: about 50 words is ok

Comment: I used shingle filter factory, but it consuming large space

Comment: If you only need the number of results for a single phrase - any reason why you can't just search for the phrase and use the total number of hits found?

Comment: I need count of matching phrases inside a single doc

Comment: Wouldn't a regular phrase query do that for you?

Comment: Sorry can you give me an example.

Comment: `q=filecontent:"Text messaging, or texting, is the act of composing and sending electronic messages"`

Comment: It wont give the count of matching phrases in a doc.
It give the total hits only in all documents

Comment: Check the output with `debugQuery=true` appended - it might include the number of times the phrase occurs.

Comment: Thank you so much its there, phrase freq count is in debug query

Comment: Is there any way to get  phraseFreq field alone from the output of debug Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `debug=results` at the end of solr url
it will give you the phrase freq also.

special thanks to [matslindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650/matslindh)